# RPG where everyone is an asylum resident and an ex-supervillain

Tags: product-identification, villain, supers

I remember an RPG where all players play ex-supervillains (or just mad people who believed to be supervillians) in an asylum. They tell their stories and can be interrupted by others in a systematic manner. There is one player who acts as the game master - caretaker in the asylum. What is this game?

The rules were available freely in a single website. I played it in a convention years ago. It was not aligned with any established superheroes fictional universe.

I vaguely remember that the story telling was said to happen in bedlam

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The game was called Bedlam. I was unable to find the original site but rules are currently available here

https://realms.co.uk/bedlam/

Just in case this link is lost to history
https://web.archive.org/web/20160806143213/https://realms.co.uk/bedlam/